# Lucene.NET query with multiple forward slashes

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

We have been using Lucene.NET for a number of years to search over text extracted from files based on user input of search terms. However, we've recently encountered an issue reported by a customer where searching for terms with multiple forward slashes is not returning matches.

An example would be an indexed value of `SB/ABC/1234-123` and the user inputs `SB/*` to match all documents with that prefix. However, no results are returned based on that query. The odd part is that searching for `ABC/*` does return the document with value `SB/ABC/1234-123`, completely ignoring the `SB/` component.

Initially the problem reported was with a combination of a forward slash and wildcard (`SB/*` wouldn't return matches for `SB/1234-123`) but that was addressed by using a `QueryParser` with a `KeywordAnalyzer` in addition to the previous `QueryParser` with only a `StandardAnalyzer`.

Here is the current code (simplified to the key elements that can reproduce the issue) being used.

```
var reader = IndexReader.Open(FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(indexPath)), true);
var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
var mainQuery = new BooleanQuery();

// The analyzer and parser for searching the index fields with full stop-words and tokenizers
var fieldAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion);
var fieldParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(LuceneVersion, reader.GetFieldNames(IndexReader.FieldOption.ALL).ToArray(), fieldAnalyzer);

// The analyzer and parser for searching the index fields using no stop words or tokenizers
var fieldKeywordAnalyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
var fieldKeywordParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(LuceneVersion, reader.GetFieldNames(IndexReader.FieldOption.ALL).ToArray(), fieldKeywordAnalyzer);

// Build and append the Standard and Keyword query clauses together for the whole field value query to pick up all relevant results
var fieldQuery = fieldParser.Parse(textCriteria);
var fieldKeywordQuery = fieldKeywordParser.Parse(textCriteria);

var fieldBooleanQuery = new BooleanQuery
{
    {fieldQuery, Occur.SHOULD},
    {fieldKeywordQuery, Occur.SHOULD}
};

mainQuery.Add(fieldBooleanQuery, Occur.MUST);

var hits = searcher.Search(mainQuery, reader.NumDocs());
```

The actual parsed query within `mainQuery` at the time of the `searcher.Search` call is `+((Title:sb/abc/*) (Title:sb/abc/*))`. In this case, both clauses of the `BooleanQuery` happen to be the same. The Luke tool commonly used for working with Lucene indexes seems to think this is invalid syntax when using a `KeywordAnalyzer` (ignoring the tokenized aspect for the moment):

`Cannot parse '+((Title:sb/abc/*) (Title:sb/abc/*))': '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery.`

My assumption is that having the two forward slashes is making it treat it as a regex. The question is how do we get it to match the results correctly and not treat it as a regex. Escaping the slashes in the search criteria didn't change the parsed query seen above or the returned results.

Our current requirement is that it must support tokenized/stop word searching (for text phrases, etc) as well as exact matches (we store a lot of invoice numbers, etc that should not be tokenized) on the same fields simultaneously and both handling wildcards. The `SB/*` query is an example of a wildcard search over an exact match value scenario.

Hopefully this makes sense. I can add additional clarification if needed.

Edit: Our data is organized into a number of columns that can store any text value. Example: Some customers put a value that is a unique/ID value (invoice number, etc) into field 1 for doctype A. That same customer could use field 1 as a text block (full name, etc) for doctype B. Doctypes are classifications of documents that describe at a high level what a particular document is supposed to represent, such as an Invoice, a PO, etc. Example data:

```
DocId  DocType  Field1    Field2    Field3, etc
1234   A        SB/2567   John Doe
5678   B        Jane Doe  90210  
3456   A        ABC/5678  Bobby Lee
```

Comment: The StandardAnalyzer treats your example invoice number SB/ABC/1234-123 as two tokens: [sb] [abc/1234-123]. That's why 'ABC/*' matches.

Comment: That's why we added the KeywordAnalyzer also, so that it searches over both tokenized (Standard) values and non-tokenized (Keyword). It seems to be ignoring the KeywordAnalyzer in this scenario.

Comment: @DanielBrixen Sorry, didn't tag you in my reply and it wouldn't let me edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Daniel Brixen commented, StandardAnalyzer isn't doing what you hope it's doing.

You should consider is rolling your own analyzer.  [Here's a .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v6Kioi#) that demonstrates SlashAnalyzer (which probably behaves the way you want) as well as demonstrating what StandardAnalyzer is producing.

Here's the gore of the Slash/Analyzer/Tokenizer.

```
public sealed class SlashAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(System.String fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        return new LowerCaseFilter(new SlashTokenizer(reader));
    }

    public override TokenStream ReusableTokenStream(System.String fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = (Tokenizer)PreviousTokenStream;
        if (tokenizer == null)
        {
            tokenizer = new SlashTokenizer(reader);
            PreviousTokenStream = tokenizer;
        }
        else
            tokenizer.Reset(reader);
        return tokenizer;
    }
}

public class SlashTokenizer : CharTokenizer
{
    public SlashTokenizer(System.IO.TextReader @in) : base(@in)
    {
    }

    public SlashTokenizer(AttributeSource source, System.IO.TextReader @in) : base(source, @in)
    {
    }

    public SlashTokenizer(AttributeFactory factory, System.IO.TextReader @in) : base(factory, @in)
    {
    }

    protected override bool IsTokenChar(char c)
    {
        return c != '/';
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it would work if slashes were the only thing we are looking for but from document to document it may have the slashes scenario or just be a normal text value that can use Standard or Keyword. I'll try it though to see what happens.